# convert view to image in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to send a chart via email in android application, how can I attach that chart to email application?

Answer (score 3):

Before attaching the graph to email we have to save the graph image into storage, For that you just enable the cache for that view by setting `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);`

Then create the `bitmap Bitmap.createBitmap(View.getDrawingCache());`.

we can convert the bitmap to desired image format as follows

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(filename));
```